# Joining a twilio channel with a user who already exists

Tags: react-native, twilio

I have a React Native app which uses the Twilio Chat API to connect to a channel. I am using this repo: https://github.com/twilio/TwilioChatJsReactNative

I am using `this.generalChannel.join()` to join my general channel. This works for any new user.

I have the token generator running in the background as per the documentation in the readme of the repo.

However, when I try to login with an existing user's name, I get an error with the `statusText` of 'Member already exists'.

How can I log in to my Twilio Chat channel with an existing user?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the `channel` object there is a `state` object. In there is `status`, which will equal `joined` if the user is already a member of the channel. Just do something like `if(channel.state.status !== "joined") channel.join()`.

Comment: If you're using Typescript, this would give you the error `Property 'state' is private and only accessible within class 'Channel'`

Answer (score 0):

There is a distinction between member and user.  A User is a user of the entire chat app. A Member is an instance of that a user being in a channel.  You're trying to join a channel that the user is already a member of. Basically you don't need to call `join()` there.

A user can be a member of multiple channels, but can only be a single member in a given channel.

Comment: And then, instead of trying to join the channel again, you should just [get the channels the user is already a member of](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/channels#list-user-channels).